# ¿porqué al hacer una consulta si no se cumple algún parámetro me sale vacía PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

Estoy haciendo una consulta a varias tablas, de una selecciono los datos de alumnos y de otra las fotografías, hago un json y lo muestro después con javascript. Si no existe fotografía del alumno, se rompe el encode del Json,  podría hacerlo con los datos de la tabla alumnos aunque no tuviera fotografía, pero no lo hace...
Mi consulta sql es la siguiente:

```
$alumno = $_POST['alumno'];
$consulta = SELECT vw_alumnos.id_alumno, vw_alumnos.curso_id_code, vw_alumnos.curso, vw_alumnos.apellidos, vw_alumnos.nombre, vl_images.alumno, vl_images.principal
    FROM vw_alumnos, vl_images
    WHERE vw_alumnos.nombre in (".ltrim($alumno,',').") and vl_images.principal = 'true' and vl_images.curso_id_code = vw_alumnos.curso_id_code ORDER BY vw_alumnos.nombre";

$statement = $cnn->prepare( $consulta );
    
    $valor= $statement->execute();
    
    if( $valor){
        while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data["data"][] = $resultado;
        }
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $conexion = null;
```

Y lo recojo en Javascript

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
       var datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       for(var i in datos.data){
        document.getElementById("nameEsp").innerHTML = " 
            <h2>"+datos.data[i].nombre+"<h2>";
        if(datos.data[i].principal === true){
                        document.getElementById("IMGprincipal").innerHTML = "<img id='grande' src="+datos.data[i].imagen+" width='100%'/>";
                        document.getElementById("alumno").innerHTML = datos.data[i].alumno;
                    }else{
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.innerHTML = "<img src="+datos.data[i].imagen+" title="+ datos.data[i].alumno +" onclick='cambios()'>";
                        document.querySelector("#peques").append(li);
                    }
       }
}
```

Meto el nombre del alumno y las fotos, la principal por un lado y si tiene otras, en una  a modo de galería que en función de que clickes en una u otra cambia la foto.
Intenté hacer algo del estilo:

```
$alumno = $_POST['alumno'];
$consulta = SELECT vw_alumnos.id_alumno, vw_alumnos.curso_id_code, vw_alumnos.curso, vw_alumnos.apellidos, vw_alumnos.nombre, vl_images.alumno, vl_images.principal
    FROM vw_alumnos, vl_images
    WHERE 1=1; 
if($_POST["alumno"] != ""){
        $consulta .= " and vw_alumnos.nombre in (".ltrim($alumno,',').")";
    }
    $consulta .= " and vl_images.principal = 'true' and vl_images.curso_id_code = vw_alumnos.curso_id_code";
$consulta .= ' ORDER BY vw_alumnos.nombre';
```

Pero creo que me he liado, porque no funciona.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `IN` en lugar de `=` o `LIKE` para el nombre del alumno? Por otra parte, seguramente el problema no es la consulta, sino cómo envías los resultados o cómo los manejas en Javascript.

Comment: modifiqué la pregunta añadiendo como construyo el JSON y como lo recojo después en Javascript @Triby

Comment: puedes añadir un ejemplo del JSON que te devuelve?

Comment: Hay algo que es clave en programación: **aprender a depurar**. Eso te ahorrará horas, días, meses y te quitará muchas comederas de coco. Entonces pregunto, ¿has depurado?, sí, no. Si es sí, ¿qué has depurado? ¿qué resultados obtienes? (pulsa en [edit] y agrega los resultados de tu depuración, así aceleras cualquier ayuda que podamos brindarte). ¿No has depurado? entonces muy mal... ¿por qué no lo has hecho? Debes aprender a hacerlo y si aprendes, aumentarás tu rendimiento en programación al menos en un 75%, te lo digo en serio.

Comment: Tienes razón, @A.Cedano lo bueno de estar aprendiendo a hacer algo, es que te permite un margen de mejora. Me quedé con el error que me dio, tendré que depurar el Javascript, pq la consulta  si se cumple que encuentra imagen funciona, ni no encuentra imagen es cuando me devuelve el error de que no puede hacer el JSON.

Comment: Casi siempre eso ocurre porque en el código PHP no se manejan adecuadamente las situaciones de error. Me explico: cuando mandas una petición desde Ajax a PHP y el tipo de dato esperado es un JSON, en PHP debes programar de modo que **pase lo que pase** la respuesta sea un JSON. He visto infinidad de veces que muchos programadores resuelven los errores con un simple `die` o un `echo` en caso de error, **ignorando así que el cliente espera un JSON**. Cuando hay error, debes por tanto crear un array con una clave `error`, un mensaje de error, y devolver ese array con `json_encode`.

Comment: Efectivamente @A.Cedano, estoy devolviendo un echo, OK, tienes razón, devolveré un json_encode y en Javascript lo controlaré para que me muestre una imagen dummie. Gracias.